# Simple Calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

I tried to make a really simple calculator. so far this is what i have, but I am getting really obscure answers. Like, for multiplying 2 and 2 i get 1550532996. all help appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x;
int b;
int k;
int sum=x+b;
int difference=x-b;
int product=x*b;
int quotient=x/b;
cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Enter another number."<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<"What do you want to do with these numbers? Enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, and 4 for division"<<endl;
cin>>k;
    switch (k){

    case 1:
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    break;

    case 2:
    cout<<difference<<endl;
    break;

    case 3:
    cout<<product<<endl;
    break;

    case 4:
    cout<<quotient<<endl;
    break;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to do your calculations *after* you assign values to your input variables.

Comment: C++ is not a *declarative* language, it's an *imperative* one. Look up what this means in the context of programming, and then you'll be a lot less confused.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
int x;
int b;
int k;
int sum=x+b;
int difference=x-b;
int product=x*b;
int quotient=x/b;
cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Enter another number."<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<"What do you want to do with these numbers? Enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, and 4 for division"<<endl;
cin>>k;
```

by

```
int x;
int b;
int k;
cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Enter another number."<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<"What do you want to do with these numbers? Enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, and 4 for division"<<endl;
cin>>k;
int sum=x+b;
int difference=x-b;
int product=x*b;
int quotient=x/b;
```

int sum=x+b is not a function but only a variable set to (x+b).

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that you do the calculations before reading the input from the user. Since your variables are uninitialized they hold some random stuff (probably what happened to be at that position in memory before). That's the reason you get wrong results.

```
int x;
int b;
int k;
int sum=x+b;
int difference=x-b;
int product=x*b;
int quotient=x/b;
cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Enter another number."<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<"What do you want to do with these numbers? Enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, and 4 for division"<<endl;
cin>>k;
```

should be changed into something like that:

```
int x;
int b;
int k;
cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Enter another number."<<endl;
cin>>b;
int sum=x+b;
int difference=x-b;
int product=x*b;
int quotient=x/b;
cout<<"What do you want to do with these numbers? Enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, and 4 for division"<<endl;
cin>>k;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take input from user first and then do the calculations, otherwise the program takes some random values already placed inside the variables and calculates the result instead of taking it from the user.
Correct code:

```
int x;
int b;
int k;
cout<<"Enter a number"<<endl;
cin>>x;
cout<<"Enter another number."<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<"What do you want to do with these numbers? Enter 1for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, and 4 for division"<<endl;
cin>>k;
int sum=x+b;
int difference=x-b;
int product=x*b;
int quotient=x/b;
```